# 6-31G basis set of Silicon and the p-orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

Following is the 6-31G basis set of silicon. The numbers in the bracket denotes power raised to 10, e.g. $1.231(+3)=1.231 * 10^3$

[image]

Now silicon is $1s^22s^22p_x^22p_y^22p_z^23s^23p_x^13p_y^1$.

Now I am trying to understand the basis for 2SP and 3SP.

Lets consider 2SP. The exponent is identical for both $2s$ and $2p$ orbitals for ease of calculation. But I can construct only one 2p orbital from the information given in the table. There is no distinction between $2p_x,2p_y,2p_z$, atleast the p-coefficients are supposed to be different. Moreover each atomic orbital are going to contain two electrons at most. If there is only one $2p$ atomic orbital defined, in that case I can only insert two electrons in it. So then rest of the four electrons of $2p$ subshell go unaccounted for becuase I can not insert six electrons in a single atomic orbital, i.e. $2p_x$, lets say.

I am missing something. Can someone kindly help me out here?

**EDIT:**

Or is it that at $2p$ level, all $2p_x,2p_y,2p_z$ have the same functional form.

And then at $3p$ level, I have $3p,3p^{'}$ defined.

Then $3p$= $-0.0151774e^{1.65} + 0.0275139e^{5.4}+0.783e^{2.044}$
and $3p^{'}$= $e^{0.07238}$

Finally,

$3p_x=c_1*3p + c_2*3p^{'}$

$3p_y=c_3*3p + c_4*3p^{'}$

$3p_z=c_5*3p + c_6*3p^{'}$

Where all the coefficients $c_1, c_2,...,c_6$ are different.

This is the only explanation I can think of the above table. Can someone drop a pointer please?

Comment: In a hurry but briefly the above table is essentially coefficients for the radial dependency of the wavefunction. px, py and pz have the same radial dependency but different angular dependency - so they have all the same coefficients and exponents, but px is multiplied by x, py is multiplied by y and pz by z. When time  will write a proper answer talking about real solid harmonics